# IIS: Difference between Websites and App Pools when stopping/starting/deploying

Tags: iis, iis8

I've used IIS here and there for various applications, mostly as a developer that doesn't have to interact with it much. I've never understood the complete distinction between an IIS "Website" and an Application Pool. With this new project I am working on I am even more confused since we have what seems to be layers of App Pools:

Our IIS panel:

```
LOCALHOST
^ Application Pools
> Sites
  > WebsiteX       (Main App Pool)
    > dev          (Dev App Pool, static files)
      ^ ServiceA  ]\
      ^ ServiceB  ] Service App Pool
      ^ ServiceC  ]/
```

When deploying our application, or parts thereof, which services need to be stopped? I noticed if I stop the Service App Pool I can update the services (if I don't, I get file in use errors). Do I need to stop the Dev App Pool when updating static files? Do I even need the Dev App Pool, or the Main App Pool?

I was under the impression that App Pools are tied to backend applications only. That is, that they aren't needed for serving static files.

I noticed that I can also stop the entire WebsiteX and am able to deploy new releases, without stopping any App Pools. What does that do? Just close connections but leave any applications running?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!